# Regex to remove all numbers before a specific character (working in R)

Tags: r, regex

I'm looking for regex to remove all numbers before the first appearance of an underscore ( _ ).

Here's an example of a string I want to modify -

```
"123-abc-123_abc-123_abc_123_abc"
```

Here's the desired result -

```
"-abc-_abc-123_abc_123_abc"
```

I've tried a bunch of things.  Positive lookaheads seem like they'd work.  For instance I tried this -

```
str_replace_all("123-abc-123_abc-123_abc_123_abc", "[0-9]*(?=.*_)", "")
```

But that matches all numbers that have an underscore in front of them, not just the numbers before the first instance of an underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- "123-abc-123_abc-123_abc_123_abc"
gsub("\\G([^_\\d]*)\\d", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vzHVlo/1). The regex matches

- `\G` - start of string or end of the previous match
- `([^_\d]*)` - Group 1 (its value is referred to with `\1` placeholder from the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars other than a digit or `_`
- `\d` - a digit.

Or, use

```
library(stringr)
x <- "123-abc-123_abc-123_abc_123_abc"
str_replace(x, "\\d[^_]*", function(m) { gsub("\\d", "", m) })
[1] "-abc-_abc-123_abc_123_abc"
```

The `\d[^_]*` pattern will match a digit and all 0 or more chars other than `_` after it, `str_replace` will only handle the first occurrence, replacing the match with its copy from which all digits are removed by means of `function(m) { gsub("\\d", "", m) }`.

See the [R demo online](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJOrQsFGV0HJ0MhYNzEpWRdIxyPR8VBaiSu9uDRJQykmxl0jOi4@JiYlVksTSCrpKADFDIFUhY5CQWpRjm1IUKirJhfQ9Pii1IKcxORUjQqwmhSgtlgtoMK00rzkksz8PI1cTYVqBZixYJOAGChYq/n/PwA)

Comment: DIdn't realize functions could be used in the replacement argument of str_replace.  Thanks for providing both stringr and base r solutions.

Comment: @bbspring The two solutions differ in readability and probably speed, the first should be faster (did not test, but usually non-callback plain regex solutions are faster) while the second is just simpler for the programmer eye.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to capture in group 1 matching from the first underscore to the end of the string or to match 1+ digits.

```
(_.*$)|\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ymTygz/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/4mIWVe)

In the replacement use the first capturing group.

```
s <- "123-abc-123_abc-123_abc_123_abc"
gsub("(_.*$)|\\d+", "\\1", s)
```

Result

```
[1] "-abc-_abc-123_abc_123_abc"
```

Comment: Cool.  This non-perl solution is also useful for my purposes.  Thanks.